# Kubernetes: Edit Heapster deployment in kube-system namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I use the Kubernetes system provided by Google Container Engine.
When I try to edit the Heapster deployment to add an influxdb sink:

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system edit deployment/heapster-v1.2.0.1
```

Everything works well, I get the following response:

```
deployment "heapster-v1.2.0.1" edited
```

The pods are recreated successfully but after about 1 minute, the deployment is reverted to its default value.

I thought maybe it was the sink configuration line that I added that was the problem, so I tried to edit the deployment again, but just to add a simple label:

```
  labels:
    k8s-app: heapster
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    version: v1.2.0.1
    test: test
```

Same thing happens, the deployment is reverted to its original config after 1 minute. I type the following command and the label is gone:

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system get -o yaml deployment/heapster-v1.2.0.1
```

Anyone has an idea how I can edit this Heapster deployment?

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same scenario. I need to add influxdb sink to the existing heapster pod. Can you suggest me a way to edit this?

Comment: I am looking to do this via API. I missed out to mention this.

Comment: @SujaiSivasamy I ended up creating an heapster deployment in the default namespace instead of kube-system

Comment: I am trying the same. But i am stuck in providing authentication for the heapster deployment to talk to the secured kube API server. I have posted a question regarding the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731637/provide-authentication-for-heapster-to-connect-to-secured-kube-api-server-in-gke

Comment: @Mathew Apparently, custom configuration aren't supported. Either disable Cloud Monitoring or create another instance of Heapster. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45910248/1657309)