# Provide authentication for heapster to connect to secured kube API server in GKE

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, google-kubernetes-engine, heapster

I am trying to deploy **heapster** in a cluster and collect metrics and store it in **Influxdb**. I can provide **sink** for **Influxdb**. But I am not sure how to provide the value for **--source** flag to connect to the **secured kube API server**. Can someone help me to find out this.

> Note: I am trying to deploy heapster in the same cluster where the
>   kube API server is running.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you using? And is it on Google Container Engine?

Comment: Yes, its running on Google Container Engine. Master version is 1.5.6 and the heapster docker image that I used to deploy is kubernetes/heapster:v0.13.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution for this. The parameter that I am using is

> --source=kubernetes:https://masterIP?auth=/var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig&apiVersion=v1
>
> --sink=influxdb:http://influxdbIP:8086?user=xxx&pw=xxx&db=xxx

I mounted `/var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig` to the heapster container which is used by the kube-proxy and now the heapster can talk to the secured API server. 
Also I changed the heapster image to `gcr.io/google_containers/heapster:v1.2.0`

> Note: InfluxDB must be of the latest version in order to make this work. I am using v1.2

I am not sure if this is the right method. But it works out for me.

Thank you for all responses.

Answer (score 1):

I use heapster with parameter

> --source=kubernetes:http://kubernetes.default?inClusterConfig=false&insecure=true&auth=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

- `inClusterConfig=false` means I don't use serviceaccount in cluster.
- `insecure=true` means I trust ApiServer in this cluster.
- Most importantly, `auth=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` is the auth config when try to connect to ApiServer, this is the same kubeconfig your kubectl/kubelet use. You can mount this config into heapster pod using Configmap or normal Volume.

More source configuration, you can ref [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/source-configuration.md)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately I couldn't find any /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf file in the specified location. Is there any other file that I can use for authentication?