# Kubernetes : configuring custom influxdb sink for heapster running in kube-system namespace on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, influxdb, heapster

I need to configure heapster to send kubernetes cluster metrics to our custom influx db server . For this I tried to edit heapster deployment in kube-system namespace but after some time deployment is getting reverted to original state .
I am using GKE , master version is 1.5.7 and node version is 1.5.6 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for now, a custom configuration of addons is not supported on GKE. Any changes to the default Heapster configuration will be reverted by [addon-manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/addon-manager).

If the default Heapster configuration doesn't work for you, consider turning it off. In order to do that you need to disable Cloud Monitoring and Horizontal Pod Autoscaler. Please bear in mind that without the default Heapster you won't get metrics in Stackdriver or have the ability to use HPA.

Having two Heapster instances is also fine. You can create your own instance of Heapster with the configuration you need. Here's an [example deployment spec](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb/heapster.yaml).

Comment: Thanks , I ended up creating two deployment for heapster .